# Are there any disadvantages of setting `noclobber`?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Given that `zsh` can clobber all files given the command:

```
>*
```

I'm thinking that setting the option `noclobber` would be a good idea.

I can always use `>| file` if I want to use the default clobber behaviour in both bash and zsh. (zsh also allows the alternative syntax `>!file`).

I'm guessing `noclobber` is unset by default because of POSIX compatibility, but just to be sure:

Are there any downsides to setting `noclobber`?

Is there anyway to set `noclobber` only for the interactive shell?

Comment: I'm surprised zsh doesn't at least warn about that, given that it does warn about something like `rm *`...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The reason `noclobber` is not set by default is tradition. As a matter of user interface design, it's a good idea to make “create this new file” the easy action and to put an extra hurdle the more dangerous action “either create a new file or overwrite an existing file”. Thus `noclobber` is a good idea (`>` to create a new file, `>|` to potentially overwrite an existing file) and it would likely have been the default if the shell had been designed a few decades later.

I strongly recommend to use the following in your interactive shell startup file (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc`):

```
set -o noclobber
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

In each case (redirection, copying, moving), the goal is to add an extra hurdle when the operation may have the side effect of erasing some existing data, even though erasing existing data is not the primary goal of the operation. I don't put `rm -i` in this list because erasing data is the primary goal of `rm`.

Do note that `noclobber` and `-i` are *safety nets*. If they trigger, *you've done something wrong*. So don't use them as an excuse to not check what you're overwriting! The point is that you should have checked that the output file doesn't exist. If you're told `file exists: foo` or `overwrite 'foo'?`, it means you made a mistake and you should feel bad and be more careful. In particular, don't get into the habit of saying `y` if prompted to overwrite (arguably, the aliases should be `alias cp='yes n | cp -i' mv='yes n | mv -i'`, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> makes the output look better): if you did mean to overwrite, cancel the command, move or remove the output file, and run the command again.

It's also important not to get into the habit of triggering those safeties because if you do, one day you'll be on a machine which doesn't have your configuration, and you'll lose data because the protections you were counting on aren't there.

`noclobber` will only be set for interactive shells, since `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` is only read by interactive shells. Of course you shouldn't change shell options in a way that would affect scripts, since it could break those scripts.

Comment: `rm` has an option `-I` that I use and recommend: "prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively; less intrusive than `-i`, while still giving protection against most mistakes"

Comment: I strongly recommend **not** re-aliasing cp and mv that way. However, using `-i` as a default argument to them is an excellent idea, but it should be applied at *different alias names*, not the originals (for instance I always put `alias copy="cp -i"` and `alias move="mv -i"` in my .bashrc). Why? Because of failure mode. What happens when you use a machine or different user that does not have the cp/mv aliases? Files potentially overwritten unintentionally (possibly undetected!). Corresponding failure mode with copy/move alias: shell complains that it does not recognise the command.

Comment: There is also an additional failure mode for cp/mv alias: when writing a shell script someone that is used to cp="cp -i" alias could write a cp command incorrectly expecting it to behave like in an interactive mode because there is no name difference. In contrast, every time I write "copy somefile /some/where" I know that I use an alias and not the cp command directly. And even if I should put a copy into a shell file it would fail the same way as for shell with missing alias.

Comment: So TL;DR the advice to default to use the `-i` argument for cp and mv is excellent, but the advice to reuse the cp and mv names is horribly bad. It is so bad I have to give the answer a down vote. Please change to use different alias names and I will give it an up vote.

Comment: @hlovdal That's debatable and I'm firmly on the other side of this debate. Lose data now or risk losing data later? By the same token I guess you recommend against using noclobber, and using some different way to redirect to a file? But I have added a note to explain that this is a safety net, and not something you're supposed to get into the habit of triggering. If you're counting on those aliases, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Based on @Reid's comment, I set up: `alias rm='rm -I'  # Prompt on -r or >3 files`
`alias RM='rm --interactive=never'  # Undo the -I`

Comment: @TomHale You could use `alias RM='command rm'`, which would tell zsh to use the external command `rm` instead of the alias. That way you do not have to rely on `--interactive=never` superseding a previous `-i`.

Comment: Once I answered a question suggesting the use of -i on cp and mv and rm and was heavily downvoted.

Comment: @hlovdal I want to try your suggestion but I'm spoiled because cp and mv are in muscle memory, so here's what I came up with:

`alias copy='yes n | command cp -i'
alias cp='echo Do not use cp interactively -- use copy; false'
alias move='yes n | command mv -i'
alias mv='echo Do not use mv interactively -- use move; false'`

Comment: I just want to chip in that my CentOS6 and 7 both had the rm,cp,mv aliases already set for the root account as in the answer, not for regular users though

Comment: CentOS and Fedora and Red Hat in general has done this forever, which makes for disasters if the user ever logs into a system without those aliases.  (At least in recent years, it's only been on for `root` by default, instead of all users.)

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', I recommend you delete the `cp -i`/`rm -i` as they're unrelated to `noclobber`.  Even your italicized *safety net* doesn't stand out enough.

Answer (score 8):

The downside is that, if you become used to having `noclobber` active, you will one day use a system where it it *not* active and you will blithely execute a potentially-dangerous command, expecting the `noclobber` to save you... and it won't.  And then you'll have to hope that there's a recent-enough backup to recover the data you destroyed because you assumed you would be asked for confirmation first.

Comment: Sure, one day you'll use a system where it isn't active. When you're using an unfamiliar system, you should be especially careful and ensure that the backups are up-to-date before doing anything potentially destructive like redirecting output to a file.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the `noclobber` shell option in `~/.bashrc` (for `bash`) or `~/.zshrc` (or more precisely `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`, for `zsh`) will make it active in interactive shell sessions.

Non-interactive shells (scripts) do not read these files.

Shell options are not normally inherited from parent shells.

This means that you should be able to set the option in those files without modifying the behaviour in existing scripts, unless scripts explicitly sources those files.

The only downside of doing this that I can see is that you will repeatedly forget that you have set the option, at least in the beginning. Later, as with all these kind of things, you will start to habitually use `>|`, even in cases where you actually might not want to clobber the file (just like people with aliases for `rm`, `cp` and `mv` with the `-i` option always set, eventually start to always use `-f` on the command line).

Comment: With `bash`, options are inherited if `$SHELLOPTS` (`$BASHOPTS` for the `shopt` ones) is in the environment (not something you'd generally want to do though for this kind of reason).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding an alias for `rm` command also.
I am combining the accepted answer and my suggestion to make it simple.

```
# safe overwrite
set -o noclobber
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias really-rm="/bin/rm"
# safe remove
move_to_trash() { 
    local trash_dir
    trash_dir="${HOME}/.trash"
    
    if [ ! -d "${trash_dir}" ]; then
        echo "Trash directory doesn't exist. Creating..."
        mkdir "${trash_dir}"
        echo "Created!"
    fi
    
    local new_dir_name
    new_dir_name="${trash_dir}/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)/"
    mkdir "${new_dir_name}"
    
    echo "Moving to: ${new_dir_name}"
    mv "$@" ${new_dir_name}
    echo 'Done!'
}
alias rm="move_to_trash"
```